# What is the difference between a positive and negative magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, photons, vector-fields, virtual-particles

I have read that a magnetic field consists of photons or virtual photons. For a given magnet, if the field emanating from one pole was examined vs that of the other pole, is there some observable difference between the way the components of the two fields behave or a difference between the behavior or type of these photons?

EDIT: I think my question, irrespective of the photon thing, is pretty clear: can one see a difference between the behavior of a positive and a negative magnetic field? If it is they are out of phase or something even if the components are identical.

Comment: Where did you read that? It's a very poor way of using the word "photon". A "real" photon is an irreversible exchange of electromagnetic field energy. An electromagnetic field does not exchange field energy on its own, hence there are no photons associated with the field itself. The field is NOT made up of photons like matter is made up of atoms. "virtual photons" on the other hand, are quantities that are appearing only in calculations, so they don't have any "reality" at all.

Comment: I don't think these naive questions should be downvoted. The internet (YouTube) is full of science educators who are very good, but they can't stop confusing laymen with virtual particle talk, esp, the pre 1948 "borrow energy for a short amount of time"....which I forgot to rant about in my answer. Feynman diagrams do not borrow anything! All conservables are conserved at all vertices, in a Lorentz invariant manner. Hence the space-like $t$-channel, which offers no intuition to the noob.

Comment: The problem is that a magnetic field is not made from virtual photons, mainly because virtual particles don't actually exist. They are just a mathematical device. So you are asking if there are differences in things that don't exist.

Comment: @JohnRennie: I am asking if any measurable attributes of a positive and negative magnetic field are different, forget about the photon thing.

Comment: @releseabe The answer is no, as JEB explains below, so you can consider your question answered. If you want it reopened I suspect you'll need some considerable editing to remove the references to virtual photons and make it clear you are asking only about the field. I actually think it's a good question as it isn't immediately clear to a non-physicist why there isn't a difference.

Answer (score 2):

No. The direction of the field is a convention, so there is no difference. We could define the electron charge to be positive, for instance, or we could use left-handed cross products, or, you define a magnetic charge $p$ in addition to electric charge $q$ and define a new charges:

$$ q' = q\cos\theta + p\sin\theta $$
$$ p' =-q\sin\theta + p\cos\theta $$

and rewrite Maxwell's equations successfully.

Now the idea that "force is carried by photons", which is shorthand for "force is carried by virtual photons" which is shorthand for "interactions are mediated by virtual bosons (the photon in electromagnetism" which is shorthand for "the perturbative expansion of the scattering amplitude can be expanded into a power series that can be represented by diagrams in which the squiggly lines are called virtual photons"...is really not a productive way to think about quantum fields, unless you are actually calculating amplitudes...or are an experimentalist trying to figure out your data.

If you are imagining quanta of light streaming from north to south pole and somehow creating attraction: you are gaining zero (or less) insight into quantum fields.

If you are considering two ppl in two canoes throwing a ball back and forth (or a boomerang for attraction), that also offers no useful intuition (in my opinion).

This is a very common analogy, except to be like the terms in a QFT amplitude calculation, the ball you throw would be superluminal (space-like) with negative mass-squared, and would split in two tiny people with an infinity of momenta and energy, both positive and negative, (still conserving both, though), and they would throw balls and boomerangs that split into two people (well, a human and an antimatter human in an antimatter canoe) so at this point it should be sufficiently unclear as to discourage the analogy.

With all that, it is still very common, and leads to all kinds of misconceptions about virtual photons.